# Merge html files into UIWebView

Tags: ios, file, uiwebview

I have to create a UIWebview by adding some data I'm getting from my API into a HTML file I have locally. It's the first time I have to do this and I can't find how to do this.

My HTML file looks like :

```
 <h1>%%%title%%%</h1>
        <p class="date">%%%date%%%</p>
        <a %%%hrefimage%%% class="link-diapo">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="%%%img%%%" alt="%%%title%%%"/>
                %%%diapo%%%
            </div>
        </a>
        <div id="content" style="font-size:%%%size%%%px;">
            <p>%%%chapo%%%</p>
            <p>%%%html%%%</p>
            <p class="source">%%%author%%%</p>
        </div>
```

and my data :

```
        "title": "My title",
        "date": "2013-07-10",
        "hour": "19h45",
        "chapo": "blablabla",
        "author": "Me",
        "description": "html text"
...
```

Is there a method to do that easily ? Or do I have to detect the %%% in my HTML file ?

Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your initial HTML in an NSString, you could use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:, something like

```
NSError *error;
NSString *initialHTMLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:(your file path) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

//do something to get the data back from the api, I'll assume NSData w/ JSON formatting
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *titleString = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"title"];

NSString *HTMLStringWithTitleAdded = [initialHTMLString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"%%%title%%%" withString:titleString];
```

You would then need to repeat something like that for each of the key data you are getting back from the API.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Mustache](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache) templating engine to inject the dictionary's values into the markup.

To actually load the markup string into the `UIWebView` you would do something like the following:

```
NSURL * URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]
[self.webView loadHTMLString:markup baseURL:URL];
```